# json doesn't return any value from the server database in android

Tags: php, android, json

I am trying to retrieve some values from the `server database` through `Php` in `Android`. There are rows in the server that match the conditions in the where clause in php, but the json array is returned empty. My php code is below. I think the `$username` variable is not receiving the values as when I initialise $username="11111", the json array is dispalyed.Please explain me step by step where  I am going wrong.

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","uname","pswd");
mysql_select_db("demo");    


$username= (isset($_POST['receivenumber'])) ? $_POST['receivenumber'] : '';
$q=mysql_query("SELECT `TaskId` FROM `addtasknew` where `receivenumber` = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());

 $output=array(); 
 while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))

  $output[]=$e;

 print (json_encode($output));

 mysql_close();

 ?>
```

Android code

```
    final String name=c.get("ph");

 AsyncTask<Void, Void,Void> t = new AsyncTask<Void, Void,Void>()
     {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
  String result = null;
InputStream is = null;
try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.mydomainname.org/task/senttask.php");
        ArrayList<NameValuePair>  nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("receivenumber",name.toString()));
        //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("receivenumber","9595959595"));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

        Log.e("log_tag", "connection success "+nameValuePairs);

}
catch(Exception e)
{
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Connection fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
try
{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,HTTP.UTF_8),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
                sb.append(line + "\n");

        }
        is.close();

        result=sb.toString();
      Log.e("log_tag", "result "+result.toString());
}
catch(Exception e)
{
       Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " Input reading fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
try
{
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
      String s="",s1,s2,s3,s4,s5;
      Log.w("Lengh",""+jArray.length());
        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){

         // final ListView lview=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewmytask);
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

              s=json_data.getString("TaskId");

               Log.e("taskid from server","s");

        }



}
catch(JSONException e)
{
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "JsonArray fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
return null;
        }
     };
     t.execute();
```

Comment: Can you post the code for making the request?

Comment: I have added the json codes please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request key is different then that which you expect...

`receivenumber != sendernumber`

Additionally you never pass the `nameValuePairs` to the `httppost`. You need something like this:

`httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));`

Comment: I made the appropriate changes but my json length is returned as 0